# Having troubles with a conditional if statement in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Having troubles getting my code to read multiple conditions if an if elseif statement. Not sure why it never reads the second condition. I have tried it about a dozen different ways. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code from my last attempts. I have tried multiple strings with ! in front and so forth. Still wont read the second statement.

```bsh
if (($attachscreenshot = $false) -and ([bool]$textbox2))
{
    newmail0
}

elseif (($attachscreenshot = $true) -and ([bool]$textbox2))
{
    newmail3
}
    
elseif ($attachscreenshot = $false)
{
    newmail1
}

else
{
    newmail
}
```

Comment: To compare something to something else, you should use `-eq` instead of `=`. With `=` you are **assigning** a value to something, you're not comparing. See [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it makes the logic a little clearer. Of course that's if I understand your logic!

```
if ($attachscreenshot -eq $false {
  if ([bool]$textbox2) { newmail0 }
  else { newmail1 } 
else {
    #$attachscreenshot is $true
    if ([bool]$textbox2) { newmail3 }
    else { newmail }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Close, but this did lead me to the solution! Some brackets and formatting were missing but using this logic I was able to clean that up and its fully functioning! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As the comment from Theo says, use `-eq`, etc. to compare objects. However, if you want to have a condition for a string, `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($screenshot)` is cleaner. To get the opposite of the condition use `-not($screenshot -eq $true)` (for example).

```
if (($screenshot -eq $false) -and ([bool]$textbox2)) {
    Write-Host "First condition met!"
}
elseif ($screenshot -eq $true) {
    Write-Host "Second condition"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Third condition!"
}
```

Comment: I get all that however I changed my code and still wont process the conditions. Even when I change the variable.  ```code ``` if (($attachscreenshot -eq $false) -and ($filepath -eq $null))
 {
  #Standard Email#
  newmail0
 }
 
 elseif (($attachscreenshot -eq $true) -and ($filepath -eq $null))
 {
  # Screenshot Only #
  newmail3
 }
 
 elseif (($attachscreenshot -eq $false) -and ($filePath -ne $null))
 {
  #Upload Only#
  newmail1
 }
 
 else
 {
  # Send Both #
  newmail
 }

Comment: @TrixRahbit, please update the code in your question. For us to understand what type the variables are, please cast them also explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($attachscreenshot -eq $false)
    {
        if (!$filePath)
        {
            stanmail
        }
        else
        {
            upmail
        }
    }
    if ($attachscreenshot -eq $true)
        {
        if (!$filePath)
        {
            screenmail
        }
            else
            {
                upscreenmail
            }       
    }
```